# jquery not working in IE

Tags: jquery-selectors

```
jQuery(".menu_left_slide li.parent > ul").hide();
jQuery("#current ul").show();
jQuery("li.parent  > a").addClass('bg-collaspe');
//jQuery("#current > a").toggleClass('bg-collaspe');
jQuery("li.parent").click(function()
{
    alert(4244);
    var classes = jQuery(this).attr('class');
    var class = classes.split(" ");
    var css_item = class.length - 1;
    var selcted_class = class[css_item];

    var li_id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery("."+selcted_class+" > a").toggleClass('bg-collaspe');
    jQuery("."+selcted_class+" > a").toggleClass('bg-expand');
    jQuery("."+selcted_class+" ul").toggle();
});
```

I am using this code for menu to open on click , it is working fine in other browsers but not in IE , can any one please pick out the error?

Answer (score 0):

the word *class* (you have a variable called class) is reserverd and stops your javascript execution. replace it with something else